# XML Parsing Error: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed

Tags: java, xml, saxparseexception

I have an XML document as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE IMPORTANT_DAYS PUBLIC "-//XYZ//DTD Declarations(ImportantDays)//EN" "dtds/important_days.dtd">
<IMPORTANT_DAYS>
    <MONTH name="January">
        <DAY    date="9"    occassion="NRI Day"/>
        <DAY    date="10"   occassion="World Laughter Day"/>
        <DAY    date="12"   occassion="National Youth Day"/>
        <DAY    date="15"   occassion="Army Day"/>
        <DAY    date="25"   occassion="National Tourism Day"/>
        <DAY    date="26"   occassion="Republic Day Of India;International Customs Day"/>
        <DAY    date="30"   occassion="Martyr's Day;World Leprosy Day"/>
    </MONTH>
</IMPORTANT_DAYS>
```

And the following DTD file named- important_days.dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT IMPORTANT_DAYS (MONTH+)>
<!ELEMENT MONTH (DAY+)>
<!ELEMENT DAY EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST MONTH name NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST DAY date NMTOKEN #IMPLIED>
<!ATTlIST DAY count NMTOKEN #IMPLIED>
<!ATTlIST DAY day NMTOKEN #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST DAY occassion CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

When I am trying to parse the XML file I am getting the following error at line 6 in "important_days.dtd":

```
6:The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
```

Can anyone point out what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

XML is case-sensitive. Notice the lowercase `L` characters, which should be uppercase:

```
Line 6: <!ATTlIST DAY count NMTOKEN #IMPLIED>
             ^

Line 7: <!ATTlIST DAY day NMTOKEN #IMPLIED>
             ^
```